# Table with 80 foreign key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, performance-tuning

I have a table with 120 columns and most of them (around 80) are  foreign key . We are refactor some of main table in our system . I was thinking of change this table to divide in small table because i saw over internet that they suggest to not have table with more than 5 index. We haven't indexed all FK on table but some of them that are most used. If i divide my table into other small table i think it will be indexed better . Do you think that this will be improve performance on the table .

Comment: What does a row with 120 data points mean? Can you explain this normalization nightmare?

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think that this will be improve performance on the table .

No.  You'll probably just end up JOINing the smaller tables together.

Comment: I think that is hard to predict without further information.

Comment: True, but the question asked was general.  And _in general_ this would not improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to first identify the workload and purpose of the table (read and write):

**1.(Write > Read)**:
If write activity is more than read activity on the table then it's better to have normalized tables, that means we minimize the purpose of a table i.e. instead of having Sales, Customer and Products data in 1 table, better maintain separate tables per each purpose. This way you could improve performance for write operation, *beware having more non-clustered indexes (without any use) would have negative impact on performance*

**2.(Write < Read)**:
If the purpose of the table is mainly to serve read operations (assume 10 to 20% write, 80 to 90% read), then it's better to keep as Denormalized table, so that it help us to avoid joins in every read activity.